# Emails do not display recipients in To & Cc

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtplib

I am trying to send email using **smtplib** in **python 3.8** with my organisation exchange mailbox (Office 265), it works and emails do get delivered.

However, the emails do not display the **To** or **CC** with email address; email get delivered like user is sending it using **Bcc**. Please help

````
EMAIL_ADDRESS = 'mydept_help@myorg.com'
EMAIL_PASS = None

to = 'myemail@myorg.com'

with smtplib.SMTP('outbound.myorg.com', 25) as smtp:
        smtp.ehlo()
        smtp.starttls()
        smtp.ehlo()

        # smtp.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS,EMAIL_PASS)

        subject = 'Test email'
        body = 'Hello, sending email via python'

        msg = f'Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}'

        smtp.sendmail(EMAIL_ADDRESS, to, msg)

print(msg)```

Please note, our organisation lets us configure dummy emails and there is no authentication required; hence skipped *smtp.login* step
````

Comment: If you know what you are doing, you can create really simple SMTP messages just by smashing strings together. But you are really better off using the `email` module from the Python standard library, especially if you are not an expert on SMTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include these details as header lines in the message body:

`msg = (f'From: {fromaddr}\r\nTo: {toaddr}\r\nsubject: {subject}\r\n\r\n{body}')`

Comment: Thank you this works and i do see the email address in the To list!! But the subject and body variables are not rendering correctly and in the email shows it as **{subject}** & **{body}**

Comment: I got it! used the below code to fix the subject & email body. Thanks a lot for your help!!

msg = (f'From: {fromaddr}\r\nTo: {toaddr}\r\nsubject: {subject}\r\n{body}')

Comment: There should be *two* empty lines (called a "neck") between the headers and the body.